# PhoneStateListener is not getting invoked in android 7

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

In Android - target 21, I have a background service where in **onStartCommand** function I have registered the telephony manager to listen. It works fine on Android versions that are before Nougat but in Nougat it doesn't work, even though the permissions are granted.